# Swift IOS, anonymous user + security

Tags: ios, security

right now I am trying to develop an anonymous social network where people can just simply post text messages.
My last step is to ensure the user's security and to keep the app clean from bullying and similar stuff.
My question: **How can I save information about the user in my database to trace them back in case of law infringement?** Is it enough to save the IP address? Or is there any kind of unique iPhone ID I can store? Or is there some kind of US law that explicitly makes me to save certain data in order to keep the network save? I appreciate every idea to keep my anonymous social network safe, thank you!

Comment: Half of this isn't a programming question. It's more of a legal question. Please rewrite your question to focus on a single, specific programming issue you are having.

Comment: What is your database and where is it?